# Sending LIst<t> via ajax to complex model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I know I've done this before but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have the following JavaScript;

```
        $("#btnTestVouchers").click(function () {
            var postData = {
                "workplaceGiverId": $(".wpgDropdownList").val(),
                "fromMemberId": $(".wpgFromMemberDropdownList").val(),
                "toMemberId": $(".wpgToMemberDropdownList").val(),
                "voucherExpiryDate": $("#expiryDatePicker").val(),
                "recipients": JSON.stringify("[{'firstname':'a','lastname':'b','email':'c','voucheramount':'d'}]")
            };
            console.log(postData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Admin/TestVoucherCreationEmails",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (d) {
                    alert("OK");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error:" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

In my model I have;

```
public class postDataObject
{
    public int workplaceGiverId { get; set; }
    public int fromMemberId { get; set; }
    public int toMemberId { get; set; }
    public string voucherExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BulkVoucherRecipient> recipients { get; set; }
}

public class BulkVoucherRecipient
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string voucheramount { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void TestVoucherCreationEmails(postDataObject postedData)
    {
        string g = "";
    }
```

However when I post, the list of recipients is always empty.

If I don't Stringify the list of recipients I get the same result.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**edit**
The other values all come through ok, just the List is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `JSON.stringify` the recipients.

```
"recipients": JSON.stringify("[{'firstname':'a','lastname':'b','email':'c','voucheramount':'d'}]")
```

Remove `JSON.stringify` form here and it should work.

```
var postData = {
            "workplaceGiverId": $(".wpgDropdownList").val(),
            "fromMemberId": $(".wpgFromMemberDropdownList").val(),
            "toMemberId": $(".wpgToMemberDropdownList").val(),
            "voucherExpiryDate": $("#expiryDatePicker").val(),
            "recipients": [{'firstname':'a','lastname':'b','email':'c','voucheramount':'d'}]
        };
```

Comment: Turns out this is a large amount of data issue.  If I only do 100 rows from my grid it works, but when I do 2,500 it fails.  Hmmmm

Comment: This must be browser limit. Try increasing maxRequestLength in web.config.

Comment: Did that with no effect.  The file is 9.2kb and the default for maxRequestSize is 4mb.  Definitely a size issue though.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) in jquery-1.7.2.min.js.  Doesn't even get to my controller.  O at least not that I can trap

Comment: PLease see the details in console by clicking that error.

Comment: f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ bulkvouchercreation:128
f.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80545/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-griegs).

Comment: Thanks for the help in the discussion.  For anyone else I needed to add <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" /> into the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should work

```
[HttpPost]
public void TestVoucherCreationEmails([FromBody]postDataObject postedData)
{
    string g = "";
}
```